# How to hide the untracked file of git in RStudio using?

Tags: git, rstudio

I am using Rstudio 0.99.335 and git 1.9.5. There are many untracked files in my local copy including intermediate results, reports, etc. Sometimes, it is hard to find the changed files to commit.

gitignore can be used to ignore some files. However, it might not be suitable for me. As I have tens of thousands of untracked files without certain patterns, e.g. specific folders, extensions.

I just migrated from svn to git for my own working repository with 10 years history. Before, I used tsvn as client in my Windows laptop and svn command in my RStudio server (ubuntu). After migration, I tried to use the build-in git feature of RStudio as my git client for my RStudio server.

My working folder don't carefully managed and mixed with tracked and untracked folder and files (>100K).

For example,

- *.R. should be tracked. But sometimes I wrote codes for a specific target and didn't track them as they only used once.
- *.csv: I normally used csv file to store the inputs and outputs. The inputs should be tracked, but outputs shouldn't tracked as I can regenerate them.
- .docx: My own writing manuscript should be tracked. RMarkdown generated report shouldn't be tracked.

All files could be any filename and store in any places as my repository has a long history.

Is there are way to hide untracked files in RStudio?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: learn about ``.gitignore`` files from ``man gitignore``

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But in my case, it is hard to use gitignore. Edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Can you give examples of filenames that would be difficult to match with `gitignore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Rstudio and don't use IDEs in general, but here are some things you can do to help `gitignore`:

> *.R. should be tracked. But sometimes I wrote codes for a specific target and didn't track them as they only used once.

When I write 'spike' or temporary code I either put them in files that are already tracked or in `tmp/`, which is in my `gitginore`.

> *.csv: I normally used csv file to store the inputs and outputs. The inputs should be tracked, but outputs shouldn't tracked as I can regenerate them.
>
> .docx: My own writing manuscript should be tracked. RMarkdown generated report shouldn't be tracked.

The above two seem very similar: tracking files you wrote yourself vs. **not** tracking files of the same type/extension that the IDE generates.  Maybe you can set Rstudio to put generated files in certain directories and then put those directories in `gitignore`.

Or you can have a naming convention for hand-written vs. generated files that will enable Git to differentiate between the two.

I know the above are just examples and there are other files you need to deal with, but you can extend the idea to those files as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I may write to RStudio team to check whether they like to add a new feature about hiding untracked files to their git client.

Answer (score 1):

> There are many untracked files in my local copy including intermediate results, reports, etc.

If you don't care enough to track these files in your repository, why keep them at all? Once you're done with the intermediate results and moved on to final results, why not delete those intermediate files? Every file that you can get rid of reduces the problem a little bit.

> Sometimes, it is hard to find the changed files to commit.

It sounds like Rstudio and git aren't the problem, then. Use the file system to organize all those files. If you keep all your source files related to a given project together, but separate from the files that you don't care about, you won't have trouble identifying the files that need to be tracked.

> I just migrated from svn to git for my own working repository with 10 years history.

Realize that you don't need to limit yourself to a single repository for all your files. Create one repo per project. That'll cut way down on the number of files in each repo and should significantly reduce the problem. Using separate, project-focussed repositories will limit the damage if you ever really screw up a repo, and it'll probably have performance benefits. It'll also make collaborating with others a whole lot easier -- you can share the repo for one project with someone else without sharing your whole life's work.

> My working folder don't carefully managed and mixed with tracked and untracked folder and files (>100K).

If you've got a directory containing 100,000+ files all mixed together, no Rstudio or git features are going to solve your organizational problem. You need a strategy for dealing with the mess. Here are a couple ideas:

- Spend a month going through all those files and identifying the ones you care about.
- Make a backup copy (maybe three) of that directory as it is. Then start fresh with a new set of directories and a plan for keeping things organized going forward. When you need something that you've worked on before, copy it into your new workspace. Over time, the files that you care about will be moved into the new, better organized repository (or repositories). What's left over in the old directory will by definition be stuff that you don't need.

> *.R. should be tracked. But sometimes I wrote codes for a specific target and didn't track them as they only used once.

All the code you write is only used once until you use it a second time. It's hard to predict the future, so it might be a good plan to track all your code even if you're pretty sure you won't use it again. Or, if you're *sure* you won't need it, delete it.

> Is there are way to hide untracked files in RStudio?

There doesn't seem to be a command to make Rstudio hide the untracked files, but you can put the untracked files in a subdirectory. On my Mac, at least, Rstudio's git panel doesn't show the contents of directories if all the files in that directory are untracked.

Comment: Thanks for your good suggestion. I just migrate from svn to git. My repository has a long history and I prefer to keep all history in the git repository. Anyway, it may take me a while to use my new git.

Comment: The history presumably doesn't include the untracked files, though, right? That's pretty much what it means for a file to be untracked in the first place.